# Is there any means to script automate Apple Watch app?

Tags: watchkit, ui-automation, apple-watch, xctest, ios-ui-automation

Is there any means to script/automate Apple Watch app? I tried using instruments for automation, however it did not seem to work, i also could not automate using xctest , using xctest it just launches the iphone app, when trying to record and the watch app is not launched. did anybody here automate an apple watch app?